# go to next LineEdit when I press Enter in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I want when user press Enter on keyboard cursor automatically go to next lineEdit.
Like TabOrder but with Enter.

Anybody has a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to intercept the KeyPress event and verify that if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed then call the [`focusNextPrevChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusNextPrevChild) method:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QLineEdit())
        lay.addWidget(QPushButton())
        lay.addWidget(QLineEdit())
        lay.addWidget(QComboBox())

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() in (
            Qt.Key_Enter,
            Qt.Key_Return,
        ):
            self.focusNextPrevChild(True)
        return super().event(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```